# Integrating Forum into Django CMS

Tags: django-cms, django-apps

I want to integrate my existing app, say a forum into Django CMS.

The problem is I don't want users to have any Django CMS capabilites.

They should not be able to see the edit bar or anything Django CMS related.

I only want them to have access to other Django apps. No Django CMS specific things like pages, plugins etc.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to restrict the CMS toolbar to super users;

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser %}
    {% cms_toolbar %}
{% endif %}
```

The toolbar is also part of the request object so in your app views you could disable it by doing something like `request.toolbar.show_toolbar = False` ([docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/toolbar.html?highlight=show_toolbar#cms.toolbar.toolbar.CMSToolbar.show_toolbar))

Comment: I think this is a very dangerous idea. The backend code that accepts creation page is still there. So, if someone made these calls to backend using custom code or embedding js themselves, it will be a huge issue from security standpoint

Comment: @Kotlinboy It's in no way dangerous. It's standard django to do that in the view or the template. The `{%` tags go through django's template engine to be turned into HTML to be rendered into the browser, so if you're not logged in or a superuser, the toolbar won't be rendered. Check the docs; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: But the Django CMS view behind the scenes still accepts these page creating and editing methods or API.

So, if someone were to know that we are using Django CMS, they could add the JS for the toolbar by copying and adding in browser debug toolbar from a fresh Django CMS installation.

Or they could reimplement the JS API calls in a bot created in any language and will be able to add pages.

We have to handle these permissions in backend. Hinding admin buttons in frontend and your project still accepting API calls that can do admin stuff by normal users is bad

Comment: I think Django CMS has permissions. But I don't know how that works. You need to stop users being able to edit and add in both backend and frontend.

Comment: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/topics/permissions.html?highlight=permission

Comment: @Kotlinboy Ok, if you're worried about that, define `CMS_PERMISSION = True` in your settings and you can provide permissions to users.

Comment: Can you add details on how to implement permissions for my situation.

Comment: @Kotlinboy Well if you're using permissions then you simply need to assign the necessary permissions to user accounts in admin. In terms of your code, you might want to look over the Django docs on User permissions; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.user_permissions

Comment: @Kotlinboy Take a look over this presentation as well. It suggests checking the user on the request like I suggested; https://www.slideshare.net/apirker/django-user-permissions-in-your-templates